# O número e a letra ficam juntos quando tento compilar uma variável

Tags: java

Estou criando variáveis, e quando eu compilo, o número sai "grudado" com a letra. Não sei explicar bem, mas é mais ou menos isso.

Veja meu código abaixo:

```java
int numero = 24;
System.out.println("Eu gosto muito de" + numero);
```

O resultado é:

```
Eu gosto muito de24
```

Note que o `24` está junto ao `"de"`, e eu queria que eles ficassem separados, porém eu não sei como resolver isso.

Isso também acontece com números.

Answer (score 5):

A concatenação não adiciona um espaço automaticamente entre os seus operandos. Isso significa que você deve colocar o espaço manualmente na string:

```java
int numero = 24;
System.out.println("Eu gosto muito de " + numero);
//                                   ↑
//                          Note o espaço aqui
```

Veja a diferença em um *snippet* em JavaScript:

```js
console.log('O número é' + 10);

console.log('O número é ' + 10);
```